# What does והבוכ"ע mean?

Tags: hebrew, acronyms, satmar

I have found this word a few times in the Satmar Rebbe's Divrei Yoel (such as [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21046&st=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9B%22%D7%A2&pgnum=389), for example, in Parshat Metzora'). I am assuming that it is an acronym, rather than a transliterated Yiddish word, but I cannot work out its meaning. The passage to which I have linked commences as follows:

> והבוכ"ע יעזור שנזכה לטהרת הלב ולקבל עול מלכות שמים
>
> May the [??] enable us to achieve purity of heart, that we may accept
>   the yoke of the kingdom of heaven.

Can anybody help?

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q="בורא+כל+העולמים"](https://www.google.com/search?q="בורא+כל+העולמים") @fred seems others have used it too

Comment: @DoubleAA Seems to fit: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9B%22%D7%A2+%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: @Yishai -- you sure about that tag? .....this isn't a question about Satmar, just about an acronym.....

Comment: @Shokhet, Given that the questioner is well read, the question in and of itself suggests that it is not commonly used, and given that a question about a raw acronym without any connection to Judaism would be closed, I'm pretty comfortable with the tag, but if someone wants to roll it back, I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

הבוכ"ע is an acronym for הבורא כל עולמים, meaning "the Creator of all worlds." To verify this, note the correlation of the acronym and the expression in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9B%22%D7%A2+%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D).

Comment: [Hm....](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9B%22%D7%A2%2C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&year_start=1500&year_end=2010&corpus=24&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%3B%2Cc0)